# Linux: Find all folders with a particular name, remove them and have a folder copied into the parent directory of those folders

Tags: linux, command-line

I am trying to see if I can do the following with a single line of command in Linux:

I have a folder called FolderA that sits in 3 different spots in my PC. I have to run a command across a few Linux machines to replace FolderA (they could all be hidden in separate parent folders, get their locations and replace FolderB (which I know where it is and it is a fixed path, say in my current directory, which is different from where FolderA is.) Delete FolderA, and copy FolderB into where FolderA is.

I know this is a lot to do and I can roughly figure out to use find command to get the locations, rm -rf to remove the folders (but I don't know how I can make use of the results in find) and then use cp to copy the folder. However how can I do them in a single line?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, I think this should do what you want.

```
find / -name '*FolderA' -delete -print | xargs -l dirname | xargs -l cp FolderB
```

The `find` command will search through your whole filesystem for a path that ends in FolderA, delete it, then print the path of the folder. `xargs -l` takes each line from the `find` output and call `dirname` with each line as the argument. `dirname` takes a path and truncates the final item on the path. The last command uses `xargs` to put each line of output from the previous command as the destination of the `cp` command. Warning: this has not been tested with spaces in the path.

Comment: Exactly like what you've mentioned, this doesn't work when the dirname contains spaces....I tried to use 'dirname' with no luck too...

Comment: First of all, `dirname` is a command--you do not want to specify a path in its place. Second, it should be possible to modify this command to allow spaces in the path.
`find / -name "*FolderA" -delete -print0 | xargs -0 dirname | tr "\n" "\0" | xargs -0 cp FolderB`
may work.